# How do I assign an error message, if the user does something wrong? Python

Tags: python

I have a directory where csv files are located. The code reads the files and creates histograms based on the data in the files.

However, I am trying to make it so that at the command line, I can enter one of the column headers in the csv file and the code will only make a graph of the specified command.  Example: `python histogram_maker.py "C:/Folder" Area`.

I was able to do that, but I want to add a part that would create an error message in case the user enters a command that is not specified in the csv file. Example: Perimeter does not exist. How can I do that?

```
for column in df:
    os.chdir(directory)
    if len(sys.argv)>2:
        for x in arguments:
            if x.endswith(column):
                # code to make histogram
```

Need part that would say if `x.endswith(column)` not there error message should appear.

Comment: When you say "in case the user enters a command that is not specified in the csv file" do you mean "column" instead of "command"?

Answer (score 1):

The standard way of issuing errors in python is with `raise Exception("error message")`. Or to use a subclass of `Exception` but in the same way. If you don't want to dump a stack track on the user, you can wrap the entire script in a `try...except` statement and use something like `sys.stderr.write(str(e))` in the `except` block to just print the error message to STDERR. Then use `sys.exit(1)` to exit with a non-zero return code, or better use choose an appropriate return code from the `errno` module to pass to `sys.exit`.

So I would do something like this (if I understand your question):

```
import sys, errno

try:
    for column in df:
        os.chdir(directory)
        if len(sys.argv)>2:
            for x in arguments:
                if x.endswith(column):
                    # code to make histogram
                    pass
                else:
                    raise Exception("Perimeter does not exist")
except Exception, e:
    sys.stderr.write("Error: %s" % str(e))
    sys.exit(errno.EINVAL)
```

See the python documentation on [errors and exceptions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this?

```
raise Exception("Perimeter does not exist")
```

[Documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html#raising-exceptions)

Answer (score 0):

Use exception mechanism. Take a look at http://docs.python.org/2/reference/executionmodel.html#exceptions